# I can't push to heroku, any suggestions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I encountered this issue,

so far, I have
upgraded ruby, rvm, bootsnap, and pry to the latest version
when I try to push my application onto heroku,

```
$git push heroku master
```

it fails towards the end, with this error:

```
remote: -----> Detecting rake tasks
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:83:in `register'
remote:  !   
  ...
...
/tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
remote:  !   
...
...  

/tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:44:in `require_relative'
remote:  !     ....
.....
/tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_00cbfd62aabf08d9eeba7a2d621c4bd6/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     ./vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `load'
remote:  !     ./vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `<main>'
remote:  !
remote: /app/tmp/buildpacks/b7af5642714be4eddaa5f35e2b4c36176b839b4abcd9bfe57ee71c358d71152b4fd2cf925c5b6e6816adee359c4f0f966b663a7f8649b0729509d510091abc07/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
remote: ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote: and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote: rake aborted!
remote: TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

Comment: tried to follow instruction in the error message: $.  bundle exec rake -P.    and I get            ```rake aborted!
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer```

Comment: did the following modifications: in  database.yml   adapter: postgresql, and updated bootsnap to >= 1.3.2...

Comment: having this error:     remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote: 
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is coming from bootsnap 1.4.1 - and I looked at the gem - their latest version is 1.4.6, and the code in kernel_require.rb has changed from 1.4.1 to 1.4.6 - so the first thing that I would recommend is upgrading this gem to the latest and trying to push again.

But the next thing I would recommend is removing bootsnap.  Shopify is a very good Rails company - I'm sure their gem works very well for their intended purpose, but if you are not certain as to why this gem exists in your project, then you should not be relying on it.  Yes - it appears the purpose of their gem is speed, but with respect, is your project unusably slow without this dependency?  Adding something to "speed things up" without understanding why you have done so leads to situations like this, where you cannot diagnose the issue and resolve it.

Comment: hi, @tgmerritt   I have upgraded bootsnap to 1.4.6 still getting the problem that Yarn executable was not detected in the system.

Comment: when removing this gem, it still does not work, the message displayed is the same: Yarn executable was not detected in the system.

Comment: A 'yarn executable' error is different than the error that you originally posted.  That should be a new post as it's a new problem.  This error is specifically that a String wasn't explicitly converted into an Integer.